# Animate second level bullet points in slidify

Tags: javascript, css, r, r-markdown, slidify

I am trying to get the second (lower) level bullet points in `io2012` to animate separately from their parent bullet point, like this:

```
>* First level animates by itself
  >+ Second level then animates by itself
>* Another first level animates by itself
```

I've tried several workarounds with HTML like using `>*` in place of `>+` while attempting to indent the bullet with `<div style="padding-left: 1em">>* Second level animated by itself`.

However this just indents the text but not the bullet point. My experimentation with `<li style="padding-left: 1em">...</li>` similarly failed.

If there is no HTML solution, does the solution involve either of CSS or JavaScript?

Comment: Have you tried using `list-style: inside;` in your nested list item element? Something like this: [**jsFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/u4gxm30q/).

Comment: I have noticed within the HTML that the first order `ul` has class `build incremental`. Is there a JS shortcut to append all `ul`'s with this class?

Answer (score 4):

If you are willing to go with a slightly hacky workaround, I have had success inserting `.fragment` at the start of paragraphs and bullets that I wanted to animate (some other things with my slides were conflicting with the `>-` shortcut, though I still have not figured out what).

In any case, this should work, even if it is a bit kludgy.

```
- .fragment First level animates by itself
    - .fragment Second level then animates by itself
- .fragment Another first level animates by itself
```

(`.fragment` adds a div class "fragment" to the following paragraph or item)

Answer (score 2):

If you want a sub level menu to increment, you could set a counter-increment in the css like demonstrated in the following snippet:

```css
ol {
    counter-reset: item
}
li {
    display: block;
}
li:before {
    content: counters(item, ".")" ";
    counter-increment: item
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two
        <ol>
            <li>two.one</li>
            <li>two.two</li>
            <li>two.three</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>three
        <ol>
            <li>three.one</li>
            <li>three.two</li>
            <ol>
                <li>three.two.one</li>
                <li>three.two.two</li>
            </ol>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>four</li>
</ol>
```

However if numerical lists is not what you had in mind, there are a number of ways you can increment a list using various list-style types

```css
 h2.title {
     font-size: 20px;
     font-weight: 800;
     margin-left:-20px;
     padding: 12px;
     counter-increment: ordem;
 }

li.heading {
     font-size: 16px;
     font-weight: bold;
     padding: 12px;
    list-style-type:none;
 }


 .bullet {
     counter-reset: bullet;
     padding-left: 12px;
 }
 .bullet li {
     list-style-type: none;
    
 }
 .bullet li:before {
     counter-increment: bullet;
     content: counter(ordem)"." counter(bullet)" ";
 }
 ol.none {
     list-style:none!important
 }
li.s2sub::before {
     counter-increment:none!important;
    content:none!important;
 }
 li.s2sub {
     list-style:upper-alpha;
 }
 li.s3sub::before {
     counter-increment:none!important;
    content:none!important;
 }
 li.s3sub {
     list-style-type:circle;
 }
li.roman::before {
     counter-increment:none!important;
    content:none!important;
 }
 li.roman {
     list-style:lower-roman inside;

 }
```

```html
<body>
    <ol>
        <h2 class="title">Section 1</h2> 
        <li class="heading">Heading 1</li>

        <ol class="bullet">
            <li>text 1 one</li>
            <li>text 1 two</li>
            <li>text 1 three</li>
            <li>text 1 four</li>
        </ol> 
        <li class="heading">Heading 2</li>

        <ol class="bullet">
            <li class="roman">Item 1</li>
            <li class="roman">Item 2</li>
            <li class="roman">Item 3</li>
        </ol>
        <h2 class="title">Section 2</h2>
        <ol class="bullet">
            <li>First item
                <ol>
                    <li class="s2sub">First subitem</li>
                    <li class="s2sub">Second subitem</li>
                </ol>
            </li>
            <li>Second Item</li>
            <li>Third Item</li>
        </ol>
        <h2 class="title">Section 3</h2>
        <ol class="bullet">
            <li>First item
                <ol>
                    <li class="s3sub">First subitem</li>
                    <li class="s3sub">Second subitem</li>
                </ol>
            </li>
            <li>Second item</li>
            <li>Third item</li>
        </ol>
    </ol>
</body>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/euq5a7zb/   Numerical  https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/jfvvu9f5/  other list styles